# How do I wrap my drawings around a circle in CorelDraw?

Tags: corel-draw

There is a Q&A "How do I wrap my drawings around a circle in Illustrator?" and I'd like to do this in CorelDraw.  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: It might be useful for you to post a link or something to this Q&A so people know what you are talking about

Comment: In CorelDraw it's called "fit objects to path".  Described [here in the user manual](http://product.corel.com/help/CorelDRAW/Extensions/EN/Documentation/CorelDRAW-Extensions-Help.html#page/Extensions/CorelDRAW-Objects-to-Path.html). If you want a tutorial, you could [search for one on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=CorelDraw+fit+objects+to+path+tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Actually is the same as the two answers on the other question.

**Option 1:**

(Sorry for the strange order of the letters used):

A. Prepare an object. I would not use too complex shapes at first to see how they react. Select it.

D. Use the artistic brush tool.

E. Save it on the disk.

B. Select a shape and apply it.

[image]

Note. I was forced to make two patterns because, on my version, the pattern is applied on "change" This is when selecting it from the two or more options panel.

[image]

**Option 2:**

Use the envelop tool

Effects > Envelope

Select your object to be deformed select one envelope type (experiment) and apply new.

[image]

Comment: Option 1 worked.  Took me a while to see where to save it (E).  For me, I found the save button in my toolbar on the right side.  Now I have lots of tweaking to do but going great.  Thanks for your time.